# Firewalld blocking port 22 (SSH)

Tags: ssh, firewalld

I'm currently trying to deploy my django app to a web server hosted by a RHEL-8 virtual machine. In doing so, I am attempting to use HTTPD (apache). As such, I believe I have to utilize firewalld to properly set up HTTPD. However, when I start and enable firewalld, it blocks me out of my VM (as I recently found out firewalld does not allow port 22:SSH by default). I am trying to configure the firewall to allow SSH before I start it, but I can't find many threads of this online, and I also don't want to risk locking myself out of the VM again. Is there anyway to use firewalld without blocking SSH/port 22?

Comment: There's plenty of information on setting up firewalld. See e.g. [how-to-set-up-a-firewall-using-firewalld-on-centos-7](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-using-firewalld-on-centos-7). Applies to RHEL8, too.

Comment: @simonz They all say to enable firewalld then continue configuring it. However, if i enable/start it, it will block port 22 and lock me out of my virtual machine (need ssh to log in)

Comment: Right ... there's `firewall-offline-cmd` for that. Not mentioned on the page I linked, sorry. But it's mentioned in the [REL8 documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/securing_networks/using-and-configuring-firewalls_securing-networks)

Comment: Is firewalld essential for setting up an Apache server with django?

Comment: Well, no, you can run apache without a firewall, but an unprotected machine in a public network is not a great idea. Check the documentation of your cloud provider, they should have guidelines for protecting your VMs.

Comment: Would using ufw be fine instead? I cant seem to find how to add a service using firewall-offline-cmd

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, use `firewall-offline-cmd` to configure `firewalld` while it is disabled.

To allow SSH, issue the following command:

```
firewall-offline-cmd --add-service=ssh
```

After that, start/enable `firewalld` and SSH connections should be possible.